# Selecting last row or record Error vb

Tags: sql, vb.net

i'm trying to read the last invoice number and display it in a textbox.....

Assume that, Table name is "MyTable" , Column name is "InvoiceNumber" and it is AutoNumber.

Here's my code:

```
Try
    Dim query As String = "SELECT MAX(InvoiceNumber) FROM MyTable"
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim reading As OleDb.OleDbDataReader

    With cmd
        .CommandText = query
        .Connection = conn
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
    reading = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Dim y
    If reading.Read Then
        y = reading.Item("InvoiceNumber")
        TextBox1.Text = y
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
End Try
```

Error is in line: y = reading.Item("InvoiceNumber"):

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException : InvoiceNumber , At GetOrdinal(String
>   fieldName) at system.data.oledbDataReader.get_item(StringName)

All i need is to display the selected "InvoiceNumber" in textbox1 !

Please Help me .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: i've tested it, it seems not to cause an exception if you use `ExecuteNonQuery` on a query, it just returns -1. It's also [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx):

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. **For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1**. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

So that seems not to hurt even if it's pointless, the rest off my answer remains true. So you should mention what error you actually get.

**Update**: So you actually got an `IndexOutOfRangeException` at `reading.Item("InvoiceNumber")`. The reason is that you are trying to access a column which does not exist(`reader.Item` searches the ordinal index by it's name). `InvoiceNumber` is a column but you use the  aggregate method `MAX` without specifying an alias. So this would work:

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT MAX(InvoiceNumber)As InvoiceNumber FROM MyTable"
```

Two other ways which should work:

1) use `ExecuteScalar` as shown below

```
TextBox1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
```

2) or using the  index instead of the name:

```
TextBox1.Text = reading.Item(0).ToString()
```

---

**Old answer**, does not solve the core issue above:

You're using `ExecuteNonQuery` **and** `ExecuteReader`, you want only the latter.

I would also use `Using`-statements to dispose/close everything properly even on error:

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT MAX(InvoiceNumber) FROM MyTable"
Using conn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Connectipn-String")
    Dim cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, conn)
    conn.Open()
    Using reading = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If reading.Read() Then
            TextBox1.Text = reading.Item("InvoiceNumber").ToString()
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```

Also, [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) is more appropriate since you want a scalar value.

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT MAX(InvoiceNumber) FROM MyTable"
Using conn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Connectipn-String")
    Dim cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, conn)
    conn.Open()
    TextBox1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
End Using
```

Comment: I suggest `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: @RamyKhaled: note that i've edited my answer. What was the error?

Comment: it was System.IndexOutOfRangeException : InvoiceNumber , At GetOrdinal(String fieldName) at system.data.oledbDataReader.get_item(StringName)

Comment: by the was i still getting an error because my value which is integer, cannot be converted to DataReader @TimSchmelter

Comment: @RamyKhaled: i have edited my answer. The reason for the exception is that `MAX(InvoiceNumber)` returns not a column `InvoiceNumber`, therefore you need an alias. That's the reason for the `IndexOfOutRangeException`. However, the last approach should also work since it doesn't need a name. You could also use `TextBox1.Text = reading.Item(0).ToString()`

Comment: PERFECTLY WORKED , Thank you @TimSchmelter , You're a prof! xD